# Why are these not covers of the square?

Tags: general-topology

> Why are these not covers of the square?

[image]

Following the definition of the topological dimension wouldn't this mean that the topological dimension of this filled in square (Yes , it's a filled square with topological dimension $2$) is $1$?

Since every point of the topological space is contained in $n+1$ (with $n = 1$) open covers ?

Comment: No, one cover cannot show $\dim X \le 1$. check the quantifiers in your definition of dimension.

Comment: Read example 3, page 306 in Munkres (2nd ed) for the reasons why the dim is two.

Comment: A cover is not every cover. Try to find some more exotic covers that make things more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You must not consider a single open cover. If you want, you can take the trival open cover with only one open set (the square itself). Does this show that the dimension is $0$? No, it does not.

The point is that **each** open cover of the square must have an open refinement which has order $\le 2$. You can easily find covers for which you only get order $2$ refinements.